# {}.format function alternative in Python

Tags: python

Really quick and simple question.

I've come to love the use of {}.format, even if im not formatting the variable itself, as in:

```
print("Welcome to {}, {} {}!".format(location,firstname,lastname))
```

as it means I don't have put commas in between strings and variables, and can directly control spacing within the string. However, if I still do it even with just one variable like

```
print("I am at {} right now.".format(location))
```

Is there anything wrong with using format like this?

Is there a better way to do the same thing?

Comment: What do you mean with "better"? Faster? More readable? In the end one-variable insertions are equivally fast for almost all alternatives while readability may be subjective (but I like `format` or python 3.6 `f`-strings most) :)

Comment: I like using it exactly like you do, but I think this question is opinion based (don't think there is any PEP guidance on this)

Answer (score 8):

`.format()` is OK, even with one variable.  In python 3.6 you can also use:

```
print(f"I am at {location} right now.")
```

See discussion in [PEP 0498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

If all you're doing is printing, and the objects you're printing are all separated by the same strings (like a space), you can just pass them as multiple arguments to `print`.

```
print('I am at', location, 'right now.')
```

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with it. But doing `print("I am at %s right now." % location)` might be a little cleaner with only one variable.

Edit
It's worth noting that this method is type specific. The `s` in `%s` means that "this spot is reserved for a string."

Also, I personally found [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/inputoutput.html) very helpful. I learned how to format strings in various ways by reading and practicing these examples. You can change the Python version number at the top-left corner.

Comment: unless `location` isn't a string, if it's a tuple you will get issues.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I'll add in my answer that it is type-specific.